# C - Should Function Implementations in Header use extern/inline/static?

Tags: c, static, header, inline, extern

I am using function implementations in a header file for simple code sharing. Minimal example:

foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

// potentially want to include extern/static/inline keyword for this function
int max(int x, int y) {
    return x < y ? y : x;
}

#endif
```

bar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    printf("Max of 1 and 2: %d", max(1, 2));
}
```

I was suggested to the `inline` keyword for the functions implemented in the .h file. However, that gives me a linker error. If I use `extern inline` it does compile, but since I just guessed to try this I am not confident that it isn't dangerous/bad in some way.

Is using `extern inline` appropriate here? If not, what combination of `static`, `extern`, and `inline` should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to put the implementation of a function in a header file, it *must* have the `static` storage class specifier.  This restricts the visibility of the function name to only the translation unit (i.e. .c file) where it is ultimately built-in.  Note that doing so means that if multiple source files include this header then each one will have its own copy of the function.

Using `inline` as well as `static` is not necessary, but it can serve as a hint to the compiler to perform certain optimizations on it.

Comment: A function implementation in a header may be external if it is also inline.  However, that does require a non-inline external definition of the function also to be provided somewhere in the program.